# Dropbox API putFile PHP Ошибка при отправке файла

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

Я пытаюсь отправить файл в дропбокс через http://www.dropbox-php.com/

В ответ приходит:

> Forbidden. This could mean a bad OAuth request, or a file or folder
>   already existing at the target location.

Ну, понятно, что он говорит, только я не могу понять одного:

1. Перед отправкой файла я для теста попробовал получить информацию об аккаунте. Получил. Все хорошо. Т.е. Первое предположение, что неверный OAuth токен отпадает. Информация получается хорошо.
2. После этого я попробовал получить метаданные файла на дропбоксе, который я скидываю. Его там нет. Т.е. Второе предположение тоже отпадает. Файла нет.

Метаданные по любым другим файлам, которые есть на дропбоксе, приходят.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все нормально, сам решил. Даже не сам, а решилось все само. Спустя 10 минут все нормально заливается.